interface error between ANSYS and Qiskit Metal
Hi all,
I'm trying to use qiskit metal in order to run epr simulation of a siomple design. I followed the tutorial at this page, but when I ran epr the code gives me an exeption (com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147024382), None)). Looking the error window of Ansys I see:Script macro error: Invalid PropServer 'Freq. vs. pass:re(Mode(1)):Curve1'. (04:03:50 PM  Jul 08, 2024)
Does anyone know how to solve it?

